# Проказа — шутка и проказа — болезнь

Tags: омонимы

Проказой называют и хулиганскую выходку, шутку, и болезнь. А есть ли что-то общее между этими словами? Как получилось, что понятия разные, а слово одно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Слово это древнее, в старославянском и древнерусском языках оно зафиксировано уже в XI веке именно в таком виде. Первое значение его было таким же, как сейчас, но среди других значений проказы были такие, как зло, вред, колдовство, злодеяние. Этимологический словарь П.Черных сообщает, что глагол проказити в XVI веке означал "погубить, повредить, извести", а существительное прокажьньство - "козни". Словарь Макса Фасмера предполагает, что проказа и проказить - от про- и казить (то есть искажать, обезображивать).
Логика ясна. Все словари возводят проказу как шалость к тому же корню. Сейчас это омонимы, слова разошлись в значениях, но когда-то они были ближайшими родственниками.
Во всяком случае, в словаре Даля они в одной словарной статье. Полтора века назад проказы не считались исключительно безобидными шалостями: это были, скорее,опасные козни, пакости, проделки назло кому-то, вредные шутки, каверзы - и это куда ближе к исходному значению слова.
Мы же с вами, называя сейчас кого-то проказником (или проказницей), ничего угрожающего в виду не имеем. Напротив, проказы кажутся нам чем-то милым.

Comment: >Слово это древнее,   
  
Людмила, какое из двух?

Comment: Проказа-первоначально одно многозначное слово, значения которого разошлись, в результате появились два слова.

Answer (score 1):

> Как получилось, что понятия разные, а слово одно?

Слова - разные. Омонимичные. Но, насколько понимаю, родственны. исторический Корень -каз- в русском весьма многозначен.

прока́за прокажённый. От про- и кази́ть "искажать, обезображивать" (см.). Связано чередованием гласных с ис-че́знуть. (Фасмер)

Проказа - (не шутка, это шалость) от проказить, проказничать. Как я понимаю - связано с тем же "каз" через значение "говорить", "учинать", сравните: наказ, приказ. Хотя точной дифференцирующей этимлогии для "проказить" в двух значениях, видимо, нет.